# Is it a correct design diagram for processing events in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, message-queue

I am not very experienced in AWS, so I would like to check my design diagram.  The workflow for processing Inspection Events can go in the following way:

Inspection Events belonging to a certain job should be processed by `EventHandlers` separately for every job. Then the handling results are persisted in S3. After finishing processing and persisting for a particular job the `EventConsumer` should retrieve the results from S3 based on a processing finishing message.

So, for directing events to EventHandlers I show the SNS topic InspectionEvent

Since handling events for a particular job requires significant resources, we think about creating a Lambda for every job.

How to create a trigger for this Lambda? On the diagram I showed the DynamoDB, that could have trigger the `EventHandler` Lambda if an Inspection Event with a new job appears. Then `EventHandler` retrieves events from the DynamoDB for a particular job and after finishing publishes the Finishing Event to another SNS topic – `EventProcessingEnds`.  The `EventConsumer` gets the message for a particular job and retrieves the results from S3.

The image is attached.  Does this design have sense?    What else can be suggested?

[image]

Comment: Why you've decided to use SNS rather than SQS?

Comment: Please look at https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/difference-between-amazon-aws-snssimple-notification-sqs-khan-/.  SNS allows to push to some other subscribers

Comment: This is a pretty confusing diagram, to be candid. An event consumer and event handler are synonymous terms. If you were going to break this into mircrsservices, you would have defined objectives. FOR EXAMPLE: MSVC A would publish when it performed some action. MSVC B would be triggered by a specific action of A, etc etc.

Comment: so...i would look to leverage Step Function for managing/orchestrating transactions. you can utilize service integration to create a step that will send messages to SNS, handle lambda, even handle error if/when they occur. No DDB necessary with this either

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd recommend using SQS instead of SNS for starting both the job triggering circle you have there, and for the event consumer square near the bottom of your diagram.

AWS Lambda can read events from an SQS queue, S3 change, or change in dynamodb via an event, so I recommend you use this instead of SNS which is typically used for mobile push notifications, or situations where you need many-to-many messaging / notifications to a group. In this case, SQS is what you want - for a couple reasons:

It works very well for a producer/consumer pattern.

- You can hook up an Elastic Beanstalk consumer app to an SQS queue and have it auto-scale up based on the size of the queue for consumers that execute on a server.
- AWS Lambda can read events directly from an SQS queue, so in a serverless job processing queue, your number of asynchronously running lambda functions will scale well as queue throughput goes up.
- Since situations like this is what SQS was designed for, it is full of features you can customize to tailor your solution to what you need. https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/features/

For triggering a lambda function from some of these sources using events:

- (dynamodb) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html
- (S3) https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-configure-s3-event-notification/
- (SQS) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

Furthermore, for your diagram, check out this tool which is great for AWS diagrams: https://cloudcraft.co/

I'm not sure what to recommend when event processing ends - as it looks like that triggers the event consumer, so I'm not sure what requirement that satisfies. Please feel free to leave a comment and anyone here can help elaborate on best practices for how to notify certain functions/resources when the event is finished - depending on what you're trying to do.

Good luck, hope this helps.